# Need to update a column in table from Form , if there is no value in the column before ,

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am new comer to Access Database. I have a table named `Employees` with the columns named:

```
Badge No
Name
Position
Salary
Address
Status
```

I create a form , in which i am using **DLookup** for to get the required data from table, but the problem is the Status Box.

I want that the status box should be like that, if there is any data in status column in table for the concerned `Badge No`, then return to me that otherwise I want to update that from Form.

For example, if an *Employee* is on Vacation it show me the "*Vacation*", otherwise  I want to Put here "*On vacation*" and then I want to save it in "*Status*" Column in "Employees" Table

Can anybody help me please,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any body can help about this Please